# HTML5 localstorage in Cordova

Tags: html, cordova, local-storage

Does HTML5 Local Storage work in Cordova / PhoneGap? I am trying to use it, both the HTML5 way and the way specified in the docs. Neither work.

Specifically, I am trying to use an ajax query result for local storage. I have tested the query, and it works.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function () {

                var uname = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var pword = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var postData = {
                    username: uname,
                    password: pword
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://www.yellowcabsavannah.com/test.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: postData,
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        localStorage.uname = data.username;
                        localStorage.pword = data.password;
                        alert(localStorage.uname);
                    }
                }
                });
            return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type='text' id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <br>
        <input type='password' id="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the environment that youare testing it in supports HTML5 localc storage?

Comment: It works without any issues in PhoneGap. Please show us your code so we can see if anything is wrong with it.

Comment: How do I test the environment for local storage support?

Comment: Code has been added, @RanhiruCooray

Comment: See the snippet [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). It shows how you can test whether `localStorage` is supported. `if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")`. So you are sure that `data.username` and `data.password` contains values?

Comment: Yes. When I just alert data.username or data.password without trying localstorage, everything works fine. Maybe I'm not implementing it right. I've been using the w3schools tutorial for localstorage, but it didn't work.

Comment: I just been looking around, and I have to ask. Does it not work because caching is set to false?

Comment: So how exactly does your code fail? Is your alert empty?

Comment: The alert doesn't even happen. When I dont use localstorage, it works fine. One more thing, I tried to do it with cache: true, didn't work.

Comment: Now, I'm testing the code with firebug, and see that nothing is getting saved as localstorage. I'm using the w3schools code, so whats going on? does it have anything to do with the fact that I'm doing it within the success part of the ajax call?

Comment: GOT IT!!!! Code in the answer... later. Cant post my own answer yet. meh

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've used local storage like this:

```
// To store a value
window.localStorage.setItem('key', value);

// To retrieve a value
value = window.localStorage.getItem('key');

// To delete a storage
window.localStorage.removeItem('key');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thats what I did and it worked! Thank you. IDK why it didn't work before, but your code worked great.

Answer (score 6):

i am using cordova to build an Android app and i am able to save local storage variables with window.localStorage['username'], like:

`window.localStorage['username'] = data.username`

it is like a PHP associative array.

Hope that helps