# Local Storage not saving in cordova

Tags: cordova, local-storage

I have local storage which works fine in html, but as soon as I package the app in cordova the local storage stops working

```
 var inputName= document.getElementById("user");
 window.localStorage.setItem("user", inputName.value);
```

I'm not sure if there is any other way i can write this or identify the value of the input field.

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804874/html5-localstorage-in-cordova